# Azure Devops Multi-Stage Yaml Pipeline - "Could not find any file matching the template file pattern"

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I am converting a classic Build and Release Pipeline to a Multi-Stage Yaml pipeline in Azure Devops.
I keep getting a "Could not find any file matching the template file pattern" error from my Multi-Stage-Pipeline in the Release Part.

**Build Part**

[image: Build]

**Release part**

[image: Release]

Answer (score 1):

In the build part you published the artifact to the pipeline workspace, so you should reference this path in the release part. Use $(Pipeline.Workspace) instead of $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) in the csmFile and csmParameterFile. That should solve the issue and is the cleanest solution without an extra download artifact step.

Answer (score 0):

My bad - needed to download artifact first

[image]

Comment: Appreciate you shared your solution here:-) It would much better if you can accept this answer, so that others could directly know this is work.